# Is it possible to jump over the flag-pole in Super Mario Bros?

Tags: super-mario-bros

When I was younger, I remember there was a persistent rumour that claimed that under certain circumstances it was possible to jump completely over the flagpole at the end of each level.

Every time I jump for the flagpole and my 5000 points, I still remember this and wonder about it. On a few occasions, it seems as though I'm about to make it! Mario is on course to leap to freedom! However I always find myself "pulled" back to the top of the flagpole.

Is there any way to completely clear the flagpole at the end of a level?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Yes, with a little practice you can easily jump over the flag pole on **level 3-3**:

### But wait... there's more!

Contrary to popular belief, it can also be done on **level 1-1** as [Mike](http://www.cinemassacre.com/2011/01/12/how-to-jump-the-flagpole-on-stage-1-in-super-mario-bros/) describes in this video:

Comment: Could you describe the important points shown in the videos?

Answer (score 76):

Yes, but there's really only one level it's possible on, World 3-3:

Game Trailers provides a great video about the Mario Flag Pole jumping myth in an [episode of Pop-Fiction](http://www.gametrailers.com/video/episode-2-pop-fiction/100619).

But it can also be done with the [Game Genie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Genie) or other "hacks".

Comment: The Game Genie.   Wow.  I'd totally forgotten that.

Comment: level added to the entry.

Comment: Wow! I did not know about Game Genie. **Perhaps you could add a link for that**. I found this info `Fireworks: Hit the flagpole at the end of a level when the last digit of the timer is 1, 3, or 6.` [here](http://www.gamegenie.com/cheats/nes/SuperMarioBrothers.html). I had always wondered how I could get those fireworks. Supercool!

Answer (score 9):

Yes it was possible but useless, only in wolrd 3-3 when you can use an elevator bar to make an higher jump.
But then it triggers a bug and Mario dies :(