# Why does Jumpman's Randomizer always start on level 12?

Tags: commodore-64, jumpman

The 1983 platform game *Jumpman* by Epyx features 30 unique levels.  The game gives the player the choice of playing the entire set of levels from beginning to end, or of playing a selection of levels based on their difficulty:  "Beginner" mode is for levels 1 to 8, "Intermediate" for 9 to 18, and "Advanced" for 19 to 30.  There is also a "Randomizer" mode that allows you to play the levels in random order.  According to the documentation:

> The Randomizer allows you to play a random selection of all 
>   levels, except the first level.

However, in practice the Randomizer works a bit differently.  The order of the levels isn't entirely random: at least in the Commodore 64 and Atari versions of the game, the selection *always* starts with Level 12 ("Robots II").  It's only after this that the levels start playing in random order.  Also, contrary to what is suggested by the documentation, Level 1 ("Easy Does It") is indeed included in the random selection.  (I suppose the documentation could be read as meaning that the Randomizer plays a random selection of all levels, except for the first *selected* level, which is always the same.)

I have always wondered about this quirk of the Randomizer.  Specifically:

1. Is the fact that Randomizer always starts on Level 12 a (vaguely documented) bug, a technical limitation, or a deliberate design choice?
2. If it's a bug or technical limitation, what is the cause?

Comment: We don't allow questions that ask, "Why did they design it that way?"

Comment: @Frank: If you would be so kind as to point me to the guidelines where that restriction is explained, I would be happy to edit my question to bring it into compliance.  (I didn't see anything specifically addressing this in the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour).)

Comment: See [our help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Bullet 2 under the "Prohibit" section is what this falls under I believe.

Comment: @TimmyJim: I have edited the question to focus on the explanation of the possible bug or technical limitation underlying this behaviour. I believe this makes it similar in spirit to questions like [Why is 3333360 the maximum score in Pac-Man?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185772/why-is-3333360-the-maximum-score-in-pac-man) and [Looking for more detailed explanation concerning SMB flagpole glitch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300511/looking-for-more-detailed-explanation-concerning-smb-flagpole-glitch).

Comment: If the only change you're making is rewording from design choice to technical limitation, you're not actually changing the question; you're just trying to word around the close reason.

Comment: @Frank: That isn't the only change.  The question no longer asks for an explanation if the behaviour is the result of a deliberate choice by the developers. I strongly suspect that the behaviour is the result of a bug or something beyond the developer's control—and if I'm right, I want to know what's going on under the hood to cause it.